# Have KeyListener listen to different JFrame

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, keylistener

Okay so long story short, here is what is happening and what I am trying to do.

1. I have a class called GameGUI, this is a JFrame.
2. This JFrame is populated with tiles(JLabels with ImageIcons)
3. I use my arrow keys to move my guy around the JFrame (just updates the JLabel Images)
4. I made a settings option, this is a new JFrame that I setVisbile(true), make changes, then setVisible(false)
5. After I setVisible(false) my arrow keys no longer make my character move on GameGUI.

I have tried the following, oh which none work: (all guesses based off Googling my problem)

```
GameGUI gg = new GameGUI();
gg.setFocusable(true);
gg.addKeyListener(null);
gg.requestFocusInWindow();
```

I cannot seem to find a way to get my KeyListener to move back to the GameGUI after I open (make visible) this settings menu then close it (make invisible). I do have radio buttons within the settings menu which is why I believe it gains focus, due to a physical mouse click.

Any help on getting focus back onto GameGUI would be much appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: I think the `gg.addKeyListener(null);` line is the guilty.

Comment: These are not all implemented at all once, sorry for not mentioning that. I have tried these all separately with no success thus far.

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 5.After I setVisible(false) my arrow keys no longer make my character move on GameGUI.

Don't use a KeyListener. Swing was designed to be used with `Key Bindings`.

See [Motion Using the Keyboard](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/06/09/motion-using-the-keyboard/), which will explain your probable problem and give the solution using `Key Bindings`.